# How to resolve the error "LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am using  `registerForActivityResult` for google sign in implementation in my development. Everything was working fine until I upgraded my fragment dependency to 1.3.0-beta01. The application current crash with the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner SignupChoicesFragment{8e0e269} (193105b9-afe2-4941-a368-266dbc433258) id=0x7f090139} is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.

I have used the function before oncreate using lazy loading but it wont work still.

```
class SignupChoicesFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelFactory
    val userViewModel: UserViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient:GoogleSignInClient

    val arg:SignupChoicesFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup_choices, container, false)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

     
        google_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

            val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), ActivityResultCallback {result->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                    task.addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            val account: GoogleSignInAccount? =
                                it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                            val idToken = it.result?.idToken
                            val email = account?.email
                            val lastName = account?.familyName
                            val firstName = account?.givenName
                            val otherName = account?.displayName
                            val imageUrl = account?.photoUrl
                            val category = arg.category
                            val newUser = User()
                            newUser.firstName = firstName
                            newUser.lastName = lastName
                            newUser.otherName = otherName
                            newUser.category = category
                            newUser.email = email
                            newUser.imageUrl = imageUrl.toString()
                            userViewModel.currentUser = newUser
                            newUser.token = idToken

                            i(title, "idToken $idToken")

                            requireActivity().gdToast("Authentication successful", Gravity.BOTTOM)
                            val action = SignupChoicesFragmentDirections.actionSignupChoicesFragmentToEmailSignupFragment()
                            action.newUser = newUser
                            goto(action)
                        } else {
                            requireActivity().gdToast(
                                "Authentication Unsuccessful",
                                Gravity.BOTTOM
                            )
                            Log.i(title, "Task not successful")
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(title, "OKCODE ${Activity.RESULT_OK} RESULTCODE ${result.resultCode}")
                }
            }).launch(intent)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

quote from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin)

> registerForActivityResult() is safe to call before your fragment or activity is created, allowing it to be used directly when declaring member variables for the returned ActivityResultLauncher instances.
> **Note**: While it is safe to call registerForActivityResult() before your fragment or activity is created, you cannot launch the ActivityResultLauncher until the fragment or activity's Lifecycle has reached CREATED.

so to solve your issue move your register call outside the `onCreate()` and put it in `fragment` scope, and on google_sign_in_button `click-listener` call launch function

**Note:** if you are using **Kotlin-Android-Extention** move your `click-listener` call to `onViewCreated()`

Comment: This worked for me. I wasn't exactly sure how to "put it in fragment scope", but put the "registerForActivityResult" variable as a property of the fragment class, (which I assume is the same thing as "putting it in fragment scope") rather than in the onCreate method or the onViewCreated method, and that worked.

Comment: "you cannot launch the ActivityResultLauncher until the fragment or activity's Lifecycle has reached CREATED." is just another bullshit of Google. If you check the state of lifecycle inside `onStart()` it will say it's `CREATED` but you still cannot invoke `launch` from there.

Answer (score 108):

For me, the issue was that I was calling `registerForActivityResult` within an `onClickListener` which was only invoked on clicking a button (the app at this point is in state RESUMED). Moving the call outside the button's `onClickListener` and into the  Activity's `onCreate` method fixed it.

Comment: I wonder if Android core developers write this code when they are high on something. Honestly, those little things just make Android development painful as if it was not painful enough.

Comment: What if we need to do the same check every time the button is clicked?

Comment: you are supposed to register when the activity is created? not when the user intends to invoke? and wrap the permission check for every call like `bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()` and `device.getName()` call instead of per class level or even per user function level? is this architecture? and why every developer should implement a flowchart for permission when it should be a function at framework level and dev only needs to pass the args like `bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices().thenApply(devices -> {})`

Comment: I recommend not to use this fancy features. In case they find out it's the wrong design and ask you to MIGRATE to new designed fancy features, AGAIN!

Comment: @KimiChiu Story of my life.  A great amount of my Android Dev time is keeping up with deprecation.

Comment: As of December 2023, this is best (and recommended) workaround to solve the problem.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using a Fragment, please make sure that you are NOT performing the `registerForActivityResult` on the activity. Fragments also have a `registerForActivityResult` and that's the one you should use.

Comment: Could you explain more on what this means?

Comment: For me it meant that I was doing (Xamarin code, sorry for that): `Activity.RegisterForActivityResult` instead of just `RegisterForActivityResult`.

Answer (score 9):

you must remove `val launcher = registerForActivityResult...` out of the `setOnClickListener`, then save it in a variable, in your example is `launcher` and in the `setOnClickListener` execute the variable with .launch, in your example es `launcher`.

your code would look like this

```
google_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

        launcher.launch(intent)
}


private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), ActivityResultCallback {result->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                    task.addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            val account: GoogleSignInAccount? =
                                it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                            val idToken = it.result?.idToken
                            val email = account?.email
                            val lastName = account?.familyName
                            val firstName = account?.givenName
                            val otherName = account?.displayName
                            val imageUrl = account?.photoUrl
                            val category = arg.category
                            val newUser = User()
                            newUser.firstName = firstName
                            newUser.lastName = lastName
                            newUser.otherName = otherName
                            newUser.category = category
                            newUser.email = email
                            newUser.imageUrl = imageUrl.toString()
                            userViewModel.currentUser = newUser
                            newUser.token = idToken

                            i(title, "idToken $idToken")

                            requireActivity().gdToast("Authentication successful", Gravity.BOTTOM)
                            val action = SignupChoicesFragmentDirections.actionSignupChoicesFragmentToEmailSignupFragment()
                            action.newUser = newUser
                            goto(action)
                        } else {
                            requireActivity().gdToast(
                                "Authentication Unsuccessful",
                                Gravity.BOTTOM
                            )
                            Log.i(title, "Task not successful")
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(title, "OKCODE ${Activity.RESULT_OK} RESULTCODE ${result.resultCode}")
                }
            })
```

Source : https://medium.com/codex/android-runtime-permissions-using-registerforactivityresult-68c4eb3c0b61

Comment: Its such a painful design by Android developers. It is such a pain to add this in different scenarios. Pathetic.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that you can use anywhere.

Looking at the [ActivityResultRegistry source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f2e05c341382db64d127118a13451dcaa554b702/activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistry.java), you can see that there are two register functions and only one of them throws if `lifecycle.getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`. The other one doesn't care about the lifecycle but you have to call `unregister` yourself.

> When calling this, you must call ActivityResultLauncher.unregister() on the returned ActivityResultLauncher when the launcher is no longer needed to release any values that might be captured in the registered callback.

This is the extension function I came up with:

```
fun <I, O> ComponentActivity.registerActivityResultLauncher(
    contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
    callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
): ActivityResultLauncher<I> {
    val key = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    return activityResultRegistry.register(key, contract, callback)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
val launcher = activity.registerActivityResultLauncher(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    callback = { result ->
        //do something with the result
    }
)
```

And don't forget to unregister when you're done:

```
launcher.unregister()
```

More info: [Receive an activity result in a separate class](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate)

Answer (score 6):

> registerForActivityResult() is safe to call before your fragment or activity is created, allowing it to be used directly when declaring member variables for the returned ActivityResultLauncher instances.

you should call registerForActivityResult before view created.  member variables or onCreate()

Comment: when you put registerForActivityResult in click event the activity state is RESUMED

Comment: Please edit your answer with your comment so it will be much more helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue and manage to get to work with some magic.

In my case, it was happening in an `Activity`, so I went about it as such:

```
//...other bits

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    // doing the setup here
    setupViews()
}

private fun setupViews() {
    val buttonLauncher = navigator.gotoScreenForResult(this) { success ->
        if (success) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
            finish()
        }
    }

    binding.myButton.setOnClickListener {
        buttonLauncher.launch(Unit)
    }
```

Where the `navigator.gotoScreenForResult` would look like the following:

```
override fun gotoScreenForResult(context: AppCompatActivity, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit): ActivityResultLauncher<Unit> {

    val contract = object : ActivityResultContract<Unit, Boolean>() {
        override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent {
            return Intent(context, MyNextActivity::class.java)
        }

        override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Boolean {
            return resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
        }
    }

   return context.registerForActivityResult(contract) { callback(it) }
}
```

Just make sure the `setupViews` is done within the `onCreate` and not on the resume step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with any third party library then it may happens that you can't see the "registerForActivityResult" in your code but it should be present in classes provided by that same library.
So in this case I will suggest to move out the lines which is related to that library from any listener to the onCreate method.

for example -

```
   btnBackup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final RoomBackup roomBackup = new RoomBackup(GoogleDriveActivity.this);
                roomBackup.database(LocalDataBase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()));
                roomBackup.enableLogDebug(true);
                roomBackup.backupIsEncrypted(false);
                roomBackup.backupLocation(RoomBackup.BACKUP_FILE_LOCATION_INTERNAL);
                roomBackup.onCompleteListener((success, message, exitCode) -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "success: " + success + ", message: " + message + ", exitCode: " + exitCode);
                    if (success) roomBackup.restartApp(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleDriveActivity.class));
                });
                roomBackup.restore();
            }
        });
```

//// remove other code from listener and shift in onCreate

```
  roomBackup = new RoomBackup(GoogleDriveActivity.this);
    roomBackup.database(LocalDataBase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()));
    roomBackup.enableLogDebug(true);
    roomBackup.backupIsEncrypted(false);
    roomBackup.backupLocation(RoomBackup.BACKUP_FILE_LOCATION_INTERNAL);
    roomBackup.maxFileCount(5);
    roomBackup.onCompleteListener((success, message, exitCode) -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "success: " + success + ", message: " + message + ", exitCode: " + exitCode);
        if (success) roomBackup.restartApp(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleDriveActivity.class));
    });
```

/// you can keep only required lines in listener

```
 btnBackup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                roomBackup.backup();
            }
        });
```

That's it!