# How to get image from gallery in a non activity/fragment class? - koltin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-alertdialog, startactivityforresult

I'm using the `requestForLoadImage` which is an `ActivityForResultLauncher<Intent>` built in `MainActivity` to get image from gallery.

I've passed the `requestForLoadImage` to the `productAlertDialog` function in `AlertDialog` class.

I'm trying to use a dialog to create a new product. and the user could upload the image of the product from the gallery.

but the problem is I don't know how to use the chosen Image from gallery.

here is the code:

```
fun productAlertDialog(
        context: Context,
        requestForLoadImage: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>,
        lifecycleScope: CoroutineScope,
        dialogTitle: String,
        dialogLayout: Int,
        dialog_product_name_container: Int,
        dialog_product_price_container: Int,
        dialog_product_name: Int,
        dialog_product_price: Int,
        dialog_product_image: Int,
        dialog_product_add_button: Int,
        dialog_product_cancel_button: Int,
        dialog_product_image_button: Int,
        cactusDao: CactusDao
    ) {

...

val productImage = customLayout.findViewById<ImageView>(dialog_product_image)

...

        dialogProductImageButton.setOnClickListener {
            


            if (checkSelfPermission(
                    context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                val galleryIntent =
                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

                requestForLoadImage.launch(galleryIntent)


            } else {
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }
        }
        dialogProductCancelButton.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.show()
    }
```

and here is the `requestForLoadImage` in the `MainActivity`:

```
val requestForLoadImage = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                val imageUri: Uri = result.data?.data as Uri

            }
        }
```

How can i update my `productImage` by using `imageUri`?

Comment: You can put ```registerForActivityResult``` inside ```productAlertDialog```

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476827/how-to-resolve-the-error-lifecycleowners-must-call-register-before-they-are-sta) question, `activityForResultLauncher` must be initialized in a activity/fragment.

Comment: You can use DialogFragment

Comment: https://github.com/AbdullahJaved-dev/GoogleInAppSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sdsol/googleinappsample/DialogActivity.kt

Made a sample activity. It's working